# Microsoft azure storage pagination query

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk-php

```
$filter = " ( redemption_code eq '1001')  ";    
$result = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities("Redemptions", $filter);
$entities = $result->getEntities();

foreach($entities as $entity){


}
```

This Microsoft azure storage query working perfect and return thousand of records from Redemptions table. can you please help me how i can use start and limit parameter for pagination in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage [QueryEntitiesOptions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Table/Models/QueryEntitiesOptions.php) for queries and pagination. Generally, you can use [setTop($top)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Table/Models/QueryEntitiesOptions.php#L177) to select the top(N) entities from the table, then leverage the `_nextPartitionKey` property of the request of `queryEntities()` function for the next (N) entities.

Here is the code snippet:

```
$tableRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createTableService($connectionString);

$options = new QueryEntitiesOptions();
$filter = " ( redemption_code eq '1001') ";
$options->setFilter($filter);
$options->setTop(100);
try {
    $result = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities("Redemptions", $options);
} catch (ServiceException $e) {
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code . ": " . $error_message . "<br />";
}

//query next 100 entities
$nextRowKey = $result->getNextRowKey();
$nextPartitionKey = $result->getNextPartitionKey();
$options->setNextRowKey($nextRowKey);
$options->setNextPartitionKey($nextPartitionKey);
try {
    $next_result = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities("Redemptions", $options);
} catch (ServiceException $e) {
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code . ": " . $error_message . "<br />";
}
```

## Update

After series of test, it will work both using `setFilter` and `setTop` in the same time if the filter string is not `RowKey`, I used a custom column in `$filter` string, it works fine. 
But when I use `RowKey` column in `$filter` and the `setTop` function at the same time, it raises your issue.

I dived into the source code, find the `$filter` string wasn't set into `$queryParam` at [line 1008 of TableRestProxy.php](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Table/TableRestProxy.php#L1008) because of the `$filter` string didn't match any conditional stsm at [`_buildFilterExpressionRec()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Table/TableRestProxy.php#L494).

So, you can try to leverage [`QueryStringFilter` instance](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Table/Models/Filters/QueryStringFilter.php) to set filter string. Try following code:

```
use WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Filters\QueryStringFilter;
use WindowsAzure\Table\Models\QueryEntitiesOptions;
$options = new QueryEntitiesOptions();
$filter = new QueryStringFilter("(RowKey eq 'E1591D1')");
$options->setFilter($filter);
$options->setTop(5);
```

Comment: If I am using setTop() theh filter can not work. otherwise filter working perfect.

Comment: The QueryEntitiesOptions can use `setFilter` and `setTop` at the time, it works fine on my side. Could you update the problem code snippet for us to reproduce your issue?

Comment: `code`$options = new QueryEntitiesOptions();
$filter = " ( RowKey eq 'E1591D1' ) ";
$options->setFilter($filter);
$options->setTop(5); 
$tableRestProxy->queryEntities("Redemptions", $options);
 - Using this code filter cannot work.

`code`$filter = " ( redemption_code eq '1001')  ";    
$result = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities("Redemptions", $filter);
$entities = $result->getEntities(); - This is working perfect

Comment: What's the error message when you using `QueryEntitiesOptions`?

Comment: Not getting any error but filter can not applying. It return data without filtering.

Comment: //query for second page data
`code`$nextRowKey = $result->getNextPartitionKey();
$options->setNextPartitionKey($nextRowKey);
$next_result = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities("Redemptions", $options);

This code not working to getting second page data. Its always return first page data,

Comment: As we use `RowKey` in `$filter`, try to use `getNextRowKey()` and `setNextRowKey` instead of `PartitionKey`. E.G: `$nextRowKey = $result->getNextRowKey();$options->setNextRowKey($nextRowKey);`

Comment: Yes i have try both with RowKey and PartitionKey but getting same issue.

Comment: OK, sorry for overlooking these mistaken, it seems that we need both set `nextRowKey` and `nextPartitionKey` in the `QueryEntitiesOptions()` for the paginations. Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135718.aspx for more.

Comment: Code:`$nextRowKey = $result->getNextRowKey();
$nextPartitionKey = $result->getNextPartitionKey();
$options->setNextRowKey($nextRowKey);
$options->setNextPartitionKey($nextPartitionKey);$result = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities("table", $options);`

Comment: Now everything working perfect. I can apply pagination in azure storage. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a demo for [How to do queries and pagination for Azure Table Storage in PHP](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-do-queries-and-08c9ee14)

```
function queryPaginationEntitiesSample($tableClient, $tableName, $numPerPage, $page, $filter) 
{ 
try { 
    $options = new QueryEntitiesOptions(); 
    $options->setFilter(Filter::applyQueryString($filter)); 
    if($page== 1){ 
        $options->setTop($numPerPage); 
        $result = $tableClient->queryEntities($tableName, $options); 
        $entities = $result->getEntities(); 
    } 
    else{ 
        //skip $numPerPage * ($page-1) records 
        $options->setTop($numPerPage * ($page-1)); 
        $options->setSelectFields(array('pk')); 
        $result = $tableClient->queryEntities($tableName, $options); 
        $nextRowKey = $result->getNextRowKey(); 
        $nextPartitionKey = $result->getNextPartitionKey(); 

        $options = new QueryEntitiesOptions(); 
        $options->setFilter(Filter::applyQueryString($filter)); 
        $options->setTop($numPerPage); 
        $options->setNextRowKey($nextRowKey); 
        $options->setNextPartitionKey($nextPartitionKey); 
        $result = $tableClient->queryEntities($tableName, $options); 
        $entities = $result->getEntities(); 
    } 

    return $entities; 
} 
catch(ServiceException $e){ 
    $code = $e->getCode(); 
    $error_message = $e->getMessage(); 
    echo $code.": ".$error_message.PHP_EOL; 
    return null; 
} 
}
```

The demonstration is as follows:

[image]

Comment: I have tried this pagination example and it works... until you get to the end of your data. I have about 2500 records in the table.  Page 1 & 2 both work fine, but when I call page 3 I get a 400 - Bad request : One of the request inputs is not valid